# Compact operators and $S_p(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $A$ and $B$  be compact operators in Hilbert space $H$ and Im$A \subset$ Im$B$.

Can you help me please to prove that if $B\in S_p(H)$ then $A\in S_p(H)$?

I have no idea.

Comment: What is $S_p(H)$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael $S_p(H)$ - Schatten-von Neumann class

Comment: @RobertIsrael and  $\| A \|_{S_p} = \| A \| _p = \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} s_k (A)^p \right)^{1/p}$,  where $s_n(A) = \sqrt{\lambda_n(A^*A)}$ n=1,2,...

Comment: @RobertIsrael $A \in S_p(H)$ if  $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in l_p, 1 \leq p < \infty $